# Soft raid1 schedule resync

Tags: debian, cron, raid, software-raid

Debian has a cronjob `/etc/cron.d/mdadm` that starts a raid check (& resync?). It costs a lot of IO and can take up to 96 hours on 3TB disks. At this time the performance of the service will go really down.

My question is: As far as I know, Linux will immediately restore the failed RAID. Is it really necessary to run this check? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not really necessary.  I used to disable it on most systems.

It can, however, be useful.  Linux mdadm RAID will only detect errors that occur while the RAID filesystem is being read or written to.  This mdadm raid check cron job, just causes the entire raid array to be read so that read errors can be detected.

In a similar fashion, both `btrfs` and `zfs` have a `scrub` command to cause all of the data on them to be read....and reading data on those filesystems causes checksums to be verified, thus detecting any errors even on files that don't get accessed very often.  `zfs scrub` or `btrfs scrub` are usually run weekly or monthly from cron.

Comment: Cool, thank's. So, it's not a bad idea to run it once in two months or something like that?

Comment: yep.  note however that however infrequently you run it, it will invariably run just when you're in a hurry :(

Comment: Try decreasing `/proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min` if an array check hurts your performance badly. However, this is probably a sign of too little headroom in your setup, because the system tries to avoid congesting non-check I/O during this process; see [md(4)](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?&query=md) for the details.